# Element wise Multiplication of 2 DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 2 Dataframes of shape (6, 4) and (6,2). Require to perform element wise multiplication of 2 data frames.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3], 'col2' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3], 'col3' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3], 'col4' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3]})
>>> df1
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     2     2
2     6     6     6     6
3     8     8     8     8
4    -1    -1    -1    -1
5     3     3     3     3
>>>
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [9,8,7,1,1,1], 'col2' : [11,12,16,2,2,1]})
>>> df2
   col1  col2
0     9    11
1     8    12
2     7    16
3     1     2
4     1     2
5     1     1
```

Expected Output:

```
0     9     9       9       9       
1     16    16      16      16      
2     42    42      42      42      
3     8     8       8       8       
4     -1    -1      -1      -1      
5     3     3       3       3       

0   11      11      11      11
1   24      24      24      24
2   96      96      96      96
3   16      16      16      16
4   -2      -2      -2      -2
5   3       3       3       3
```

Approach 1:

```
a = np.array(df1.values)
b = np.array(df2.values)
```

Tried below ways,

```
c = a * b
```

Error: #ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6, 4) and (6,2)

Approach 2:

Converted 1 of the dataframes to series.

```
df_temp=df1[df1.columns.values['a']]
func = lambda x: np.asarray(x) * np.asarray(df2[df2.columns.values[0]])

df_temp.apply(func)
```

Output:
Not getting element wise output.

Approach 3:

Convert the DF to list and multiply the lists:

```
df11=list(df1.values.flatten())
df22=list(df2.values.flatten())
```

But, the resultant list is not 2 dimensional;. Its 1 Dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .multiply():

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3], 'col2' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3], 
    'col3' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3], 'col4' : [1,2,6,8,-1,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [9,8,7,1,1,1], 'col2' : [11,12,16,2,2,1]})

for x in range(len(df2.columns)):
    new_df = df1.multiply(df2.iloc[:, x], axis=0)
    print new_df
```

This returns:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     9     9     9     9
1    16    16    16    16
2    42    42    42    42
3     8     8     8     8
4    -1    -1    -1    -1
5     3     3     3     3

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0    11    11    11    11
1    24    24    24    24
2    96    96    96    96
3    16    16    16    16
4    -2    -2    -2    -2
5     3     3     3     3
```

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation on .multiply(): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok getting the output as numpy arrays, this way works

```
map(lambda col: df2[col].values.reshape(-1, 1) * df1.values, df2)
```

EDIT: This is cleaner and gives the output as pandas dfs:

```
map(lambda col: df1.mul(df2[col], axis=0), df2)
```

Comment: Thanks @sjosund.. tried this approach. Its giving scalability issue.. Once I increased the dataframe shape to (35000,100) and (35000,2); the multiplication is going slower... The process ran for 20 mins.. then I killed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create the result you are looking for with:

```
>>> [df1.apply(lambda x: x*y) for _, y in df2.iteritems()]
[   col1  col2  col3  col4
 0     9     9     9     9
 1    16    16    16    16
 2    42    42    42    42
 3     8     8     8     8
 4    -1    -1    -1    -1
 5     3     3     3     3,
    col1  col2  col3  col4
 0    11    11    11    11
 1    24    24    24    24
 2    96    96    96    96
 3    16    16    16    16
 4    -2    -2    -2    -2
 5     3     3     3     3]
```

Or using @Alex approach of multiply, this will do the same. You can also concat them into a single multi-index dataframe:

```
>>> pd.concat((df1.mul(y, axis=0) for _, y in df2.iteritems()), axis=1, keys=df2)
  col1                col2               
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col1 col2 col3 col4
0    9    9    9    9   11   11   11   11
1   16   16   16   16   24   24   24   24
2   42   42   42   42   96   96   96   96
3    8    8    8    8   16   16   16   16
4   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2   -2   -2   -2
5    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex for details..
Could you please elaborate syntax: 
df1.mul(y, axis=0) for _, y in df2.iteritems()), axis=1, keys=df2

Comment: The syntax is as follows. .mul() or .multiply() in more recent versions of pandas takes a series or dataframe or constant as its only required argument. Setting the axis to zero means that you will multiply elements after lining them up on index axis. Finally, the for loop uses iteritems() to select each column of the df2 dataframe one at a time. When taken out like this, these columns become pandas series, and each one is passed in turn to the df1.mul(y, axis=0) command. This list comprehension is shown as a for loop in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alex for details..

(df1.mul(y, axis=0) for _, y in df2.iteritems())

Comment: `df1.mul(y, axis=0)` multiplies df1 by y but using index (axis=0) vs column, effectively transposing before multiplying. The rest is a generator that goes through each column in df2 and assigns it to y, look up comprehensions and generators.